# Deploying Flask Application on IIS with wfastcgi in Python3.10 include other source folders

Tags: python, flask, iis, wfastcgi

My Flask project includes main.py and a folder called yolov5, which contains the source code for yolov5, including the utils module. In main.py, I have an import statement for utils. When I set yolov5 as the source in PyCharm (the purpose being to include the source code and its subfolders in the build process), the project runs smoothly. However, I'm unsure how to configure this in IIS. If left unhandled, the “import utils” statement throws an error, indicating that the package cannot be found.

how can i include the source code（yolov5） and its subfolders in the build process

Comment: For Python developers, learning HttpPlatformHandler becomes very important. FastCGI is no longer recommended by Microsoft, it has been deprecated. So this is no longer the correct way to host Python web applications on IIS. You can switch to HttpPlatformHandler. I don't know much about your project, so I can only share some reference links with you. https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ and https://medium.com/@akshay.mewada7/host-flask-and-django-web-application-with-windows-iis-httpplatformhanlder-83e831ce91bc